# Example of Diverging functions with converging integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence

{Hey thanks for sparing some time I would very much appreciate your help on this problem :}

Give a example of a continuous function $f$ such that $f(x)\geq0$
$(1\leq{x}\leq\infty)$
and such that $$\int_1^\infty{f(x)dx}$$ converges but $$\sum_1^\infty{f(n)}$$  diverges.

I have just started studying analysis from R.R.Goldberg and find few of the problem a bit tricky  Will very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
2x - 2(n - 1/2n) & \text{if} ~ x \in [n - 1/2n, n], n \in \mathbb{N}_0\\
-2x + 2(n + 1/2n) & \text{if} ~ x \in [n , n + 1/2n], n \in \mathbb{N}_0\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
The integral converges because
$$\int_1^{\infty} f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_{n - 1/2n}^{n + 1/2n} f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n^2} < +\infty$$
and the associate serie
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty f(n) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = +\infty. $$

Answer (score 1):

Take the always vanishing piecewise linear map $f$ except that $f(n-1/2n^2)=f(n+1/2n^2)=0$ and $f(n)=1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.